# sort by multiple values a multidimensional array with manual sort order on one value

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array that I am trying to sort by a variety of criteria which includes sorting one value by a manual sort order.

The array is similar to:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StuLName] => Leadbetter
            [StuFName] => Sally
            [Position] => Vice President
            [Grade] => 11
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Gulliver
        [StuFName] => June
        [Position] => Member
        [Grade] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Stark
        [StuFName] => Tony
        [Position] => President
        [Grade] => 12
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Banner
        [StuFName] => Bruce
        [Position] => Historian
        [Grade] => 10
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Parker
        [StuFName] => 9
        [Position] => Member
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Danvers
        [StuFName] => 11
        [Position] => Member
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Rogers
        [StuFName] => 12
        [Position] => Secretary
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Romanoff
        [StuFName] => 10
        [Position] => Treasurer
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Lang
        [StuFName] => 10
        [Position] => Member
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [StuLName] => Barton
        [StuFName] => 12
        [Position] => Member
    )
```

The code I am using is:

```
$order = array('President', 'Vice President', 'Secretary', 'Treasurer', 'Historian', 'Member');
usort ($students, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['Position'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['Position'], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b ?: $a['StuLName'] - $b['StuLName'];
});
```

this works great for sorting by position but does not alpha sort by StuLName afterwords. If I switch to a numeric option like Grade it will order correctly but not from a alpha based value. I want to order the array by position in the specified order and then by StuLName alphabetically ascending.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to the question. I needed to use a different string comparison. The function I was looking for was to split the string into an array of chars, cast each char to int, then compare them that way.  That functionality is provided in the strcmp[1] system method.

```
$order = array('President', 'Vice', 'Secretary', 'Treasurer', 'Historian', 'Member');

usort ($students, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['SWE'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['SWE'], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b ?: strcmp($a['StuLName'], $b['StuLName']);
});
```